# How to reconstruct a surface given points {x, y, z} and the surface normals {nx, ny, nz} at these points

Tags: plotting, computational-geometry

I have 3D points above a 2D regular grid.  At those points I know the normal vector of the surface.  I am looking a command or function in *Mathematica*, like `ListPlot3D` or `ListInterpolation` to help to display the surface corresponding to the given points and normals at those points.

Comment: Try `ListPlot3D` with the `VertexNormals` option.

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime I found one way to do it.  Let's say my 3d grid points are in an array grid3d[[k,i,j]], where i and j go from 1 to 8 and every element of grid3d is a triplet of {x,y,z} data, for example grid3d[[1,1,1]] is {16,16,2.3395}.  My normal vectors are similarly in a norm[[k,i,j]] array and norm[[1,1,1] is {0.351765,0.113248,3.98289}, so they are not normalized.
Because it is a regular grid, from grid3D[[k,i,j]] I need only the "k" component and from the norm array I need only the tangential vectors, that is the "i" and "j" components.  So, I created an inData table:

```
inData=ParallelTable[Table[{grid3d[[k,i,j]][[3]],{norm[[k,i,j]][[1]],norm[[k,i,j]][[2]]}},{i,1,8},{j,1,8}],{k,1,Length[norm]}];
```

Then I created another table containing ListInterpolations:

```
listInt=ParallelTable[ListInterpolation[inData[[k,All,All]],{k,1,Length[inData]}];
```

Now I am able to see the surfaces with:

```
Plot3D[listInt[[k]][x,y],{x,1,8},{y,1,8}]
```